# How to update CodeIgniter with Composer?

Tags: composer-php, codeigniter-3

I switched from Symfony to CodeIgniter and I would like it to stay up-to-date with the framework.

I understand that you can easely install and update all kind of packages, I know how to do it as I did it over and over again with Symfony.

I already set `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;` in `application/config/config.php`. (Thanks to a lot of other SO questions)

My problem: Composer seems to update all the packages fine, but not the framework itself. Is it possible or am I doomed to do it manually?

## EDIT

Please consider using CodeIgniter 4, which is made to be used with Composer from the start. CodeIgniter 3 is old and should only be used on legacy projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter hasn't been made as a composer package… except that someone eventually did it anyway!

It is possible to keep CodeIgniter up-to-date by installing it throught composer in the first place. The project is hosted [on GitHub](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer).

In order to use it, it's quite easy: `composer create-project kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer codeigniter` should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can update your codeigniter using composer by below method:

```
$ cd /path/to/codeigniter
$ composer update
```

[Here you can get more info about this](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer)

Comment: Hi and thank you. I tried that, but that only works if I first create a project with that installer. My project is already going, versionned and shared by colleagues. I can't possibly redo it with that technology.